# Void and cout vs int

Tags: c++, function, get, set

I was working on an assignment and decided on checking this following problem with my POD. The assignment basically requires a generation of a multiplication problem and loop forever depending on if he gets it right or wrong. **So to generate my problem:**

```
int Elementary::setProblem()
{
 srand ( time(NULL));
 firstfactor = rand() %1;
 secondfactor = rand() %1;
 answer = factor1 * factor2;
 return answer;
}
```

However, I was told that this method was the proper way of doing:

```
void Elementary::setProblem()
{
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    firstfactor = rand()%10;
    secondfactor = rand()%10;
    answer = firstfactor * secondfactor;
}
```

She basically told me that answer = is already sets the private member and that return had no use.

Wouldn't my method be faster since I don't have to set the problem and then make a second function to get the problem?

Comment: Only call srand once.

Comment: There isn't enough code (where is answer declared?) or context (who uses answer and why?) to answer the question.

Comment: The answer is a data member defined in private. The answer is used to verify the input of the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A setter function, typically, does not return anything.

The whole point of pairs of setter and getter functions is that you call one to set something, another to get the value back. That way, you could, for example, completely avoid storing `answer`, and just calculating it in the getter when you actually need it - in this particular case, this probably gives no benefit, but in some cases, that may be a benefit.

Comment: Alright thanks! This was the answer I was looking for, I would upvote but I have no rep

Comment: @JackyMoon: As the person who asked the question, you don't need to vote on answers. Instead, you _accept_ the best answer (checkmark).